# Image not showing in cell excel js

Tags: javascript, excel, exceljs

I am trying to work with images in Excel js but it doesn't work.
This is the snippet of code

```
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("My Sheet");


const myBase64Image = "data:image/png;base64,iVyZgg==";

const imageId2 = workbook.addImage({
    base64: myBase64Image,
    extension: 'png',
});

worksheet.addImage(imageId2, {
    tl: { col: 50, row: 50 },
    ext: { width: 500, height: 200 }
});
```

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759590/removing-and-filtering-out-rows-containing-images-issue-in-exceljs