# Removing and filtering out rows containing images issue in exceljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

I made a worksheet with an image in each row. When I filter or remove a row, the image of that row remains.
tested on v4.4.0 / v4.3.0

I tried different way of adding images, but none of them worked , my first assumption was maybe since there is no functionally for Place in cell

I suspect that there might be an issue, or I could be approaching it differently.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook()

  const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('test')

  worksheet.autoFilter = 'A1:D1'
  worksheet.views = [{ state: 'frozen', xSplit: 0, ySplit: 1, topLeftCell: 'A2', activeCell: 'A2' }]

  worksheet.columns = [
    { header: 'column 1', key: 'col1' },
    { header: 'column 2', key: 'col2' },
    { header: 'column 3', key: 'col3' },
    { header: 'column 4', key: 'col4' },
  ]

  const buffer = Deno.readFileSync('assets/logo.png')
  for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    const row = worksheet.addRow([i + 1, i + 2, i + 3, ''])
    const imageId = workbook.addImage({
      buffer,
      extension: 'png',
    })
    const imageHeight = 50
    const rowHeight = Math.floor(imageHeight * 0.75)
    worksheet.getRow(row.number).height = rowHeight

    worksheet.addImage(imageId, {
      tl: { col: 3, row: row.number - 1 },
      ext: { width: 100, height: imageHeight },
      editAs: undefined, // tested also with 'oneCell'
    })
  }

  return await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer()
```

this is the result

[image]

After removing a row

[image]